# What does a double blockquote do in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have this code on a style sheet I'm using:

```
blockquote blockquote {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
```

Is this some CSS trick? What does it do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This means a blockquote which is a descendant of a blockquote. Essentially meaning any blockquote of 2 levels or deeper (the first level of blockquotes won't be affected).

Comment: Technically, `blockquote blockquote` matches any `blockquote` that is a descendant (not necessarily child) of another `blockquote`. And in practical terms, the rule probably means that `blockquote` has been used for indentation (not to indicate block quotation) and one wants to prevent the cumulation of such effects.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. The word descendant ran out of my head. So I went with child. Will fix.

Answer (score 3):

It sets 0-size margins and padding on any blockquote that's inside another blockquote:

e.g.

```
<blockquote>
   <blockquote>
       hey no margins here
   </blockquote>
   this has margins
</blockquote>
```